# spring dispatcher is not loading my components

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have the following controller:

```
package com.t.controller;

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/s")
public class SController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/la", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String listAll() {

        return "s/la";
    }

}
```

I have a dispatcher configuration file called dispatcher-config.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.t.controller" />

</beans>
```

And the web.xml

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
        </servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
                /WEB-INF/dispatcher-config.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-config.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

</web-app>
```

This configuration is not instantiating my SController.
This is the log Spring log:

```
Looking for matching resources in directory tree [.../WEB-INF/classes/com/t/controller]
Searching directory [.../WEB-INF/classes/com/t/controller] for files matching pattern [.../WEB-INF/classes/com/t/controller/**/*.class]
Resolved location pattern [classpath*:com/t/controller/**/*.class] to resources []
```

It seems it should work. Do you have any idea why this configuration isn't working.

I even tried using a `WebApplicationInitializer` but I have the same result.

Comment: Set the base-package as 'com.t' instead of 'com.t.controller'

Comment: @babak What do you think that will change?

Comment: I don't know how spring works on it. I had such problem before. But by this change the problem was solved.

Comment: @BabakBehzadi It definitely does not apply here.

Answer (score 2):

For one, your web.xml is redundant. Remove the `ContextLoaderListener` and the corresponding `context-param`.

Then add

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />
```

and the appropriate namespaces to your dispatcher config. This will actually register your beans as handlers.

You also seem to be missing a `<servlet-mapping>`  from your web.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Missing servlet-mapping tag for dispatcher servlet in web.xml.

If possible consider using java annotation based configuration for spring. If you are using servlet 3 you do not even need to mess with web.xml. check out some web tutorials on this.

Comment: Can you, please, give me a link to one of those tutorials? I still can't make it work. I googled and I didn't find much information.

Comment: Generate a project from this and use as a reference https://github.com/kolorobot/spring-mvc-quickstart-archetype